# Einstein warped-product manifold with flat fiber

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $(M,g)=(N,\ddot{g})$x$f(B,\bar{g})$ be an Einstein warped-product manifold (i.e. $Ric=\lambda g$) where $f:N \rightarrow (0, \infty)$ (positive scalar function) and with $g= \ddot{g}+f^2 \bar{g}$.

If $(B, \bar{g})$ is Ricci flat, being $(M, g)$ an Einstein manifold, this means that $(M, g)$ must be only Ricci flat or not? Or $(M, g)$ can be Einstein (not Ricci flat) even though $(B, \bar{g})$ is Ricci flat?

Answer (score 0):

$N$ is hyperbolic space $\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2}$ and $B=dz^2+dw^2$ is Euclidean space. Here $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{y}$ so that resulting space, i.e. Einstein, is hyperbolic space, which is not Ricci flat.

Comment: Good answer, this OP features at Overflow and recieved an answer there to, different from yours. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290446/einstein-warped-product-manifold-with-flat-fiber

Comment: Thank you for your introducing.